# How to ensuring Source Code secure for Python Applications on Client Systems

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I’m developing python django web application based on the client requirement and configuration. I was to prevent the client from accessing to my source code and tampering with my code. I tried encoding my source code into machine code but issue is that it can be decoded to normal code. I tried searching in the internet but I only managed to find outdated source and solution

Would appreciate it if anyone can provide me advice and guidance on how to achieve my goal is securing source code